# Django pass a list of values in update query

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a Django query like this:

```
object = BPMap.objects.filter(name = 'ABC', color = 'RED').values('quantity')
```

Say the output returned from the above query is `<QuerySet [100, 200, 300]>`

Now I want to use update on the above queryset but pass a different list of values such as

> [150, 250, 350]

I want a query which is similar to the below:

```
BPMap.objects.filter(name = 'ABC', color = 'RED').update('quantity', [150, 250, 350])
```

I know the above query is wrong. Please guide me how to do it. Thanks in advance. Sorry if its trivial, I new to Django.

Comment: Share the model please.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by `update`, and judging from your example you just want to add 50 on `quantity`. So you can do something like:

```
bpmaps = BPMap.objects.filter(name = 'ABC', color = 'RED')
for bpmap in bpmaps:
    bpmap.quantity += 50
    # or some other way you want to update

BPMap.objects.bulk_update(bpmaps, ['quantity'])
```

or you can use `F` expressions:

```
BPMap.objects.filter(name = 'ABC', color = 'RED').update(quantity=F('quantity') + 50)
```